# Hololens cannot pinvoke native dll with error "Dll Not Found"

Tags: c#, hololens

I tried to build a very simple native dll that can be called by a simple UWP c# app with PInvoke. The UWP app can run on normal Windows 10 computer without any problem, but when I deployed the UWP app to a Hololens, it always fails with error "Dll Not Found". I have tested RS4 and RS5 in Hololens and got the same result.

The reproduce steps are very straightforward.

1. Create a native C++ DLL project ( I am using VS 2017 community version), and write some code like returning 1 + 2, for example:

   ```
   extern "C" {

       __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall add12() {

       return 1 + 2;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a blank UWP project to call the DLL function with PInvoke:

   ```
   public class WrapperClass
   {

       [DllImport("CPPDLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
       public static extern int add12();

   }


   public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
   {

       public MainPage()
       {

           this.InitializeComponent();

           int result = WrapperClass.add12();

           Debug.WriteLine("add 12 = " + result);

       }
   }
   ```
3. Add the native DLL into the project and build and run the UWP application on a Win10 computer and a Hololens, and you will notice that the Win10 computer will succeed to run while the Hololens will fail to run.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your C++ dll has dependencies itself.  Typically at least the C runtime library and C++ standard library.  They are likely to be available by accident on a Win10 machine, very low odds on a Hololens.  Consider building with /MT.

Comment: @HansPassant You are so right. I added the necessary dependent dll and the problem is resolved! Please post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as accepted. Thanks a lot for the quick answer!